# what is the java code to get ip address and mac of devices connected to my wifi in laptop?

Tags: java, wifi

what is the java code to get ip address and mac of devices connected to my wifi in laptop??
all i am getting here is realted to android. i need for desktop apllication. Wifimanager class only helps for andriod based project.

Comment: but thats to get my ip. i need to get ip and mac of devices connected to my wifi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as you want to create sniffer-like application it is not possible to achieve using pure java. You will have to use some native calls to OS functions or even to HW driver. Java does not provide such low
level access out of the box.

Comment: can u refer some ways to do the above. codes, pdf, ieee papers anything will do

Comment: Very popular sniffing software is Wireshark. It uses WinCap library http://www.winpcap.org/ for sniffing the network. To use that you would need to write your own native interface or look for such in web. It will involve JNI and C programming, I am not sure if it is worth of trying as it will need a lot of work.